# Запретить вызов stopNativeEvents в dojo/touch.js

Tags: javascript, dojo, alfresco

Проблема в том, что код ниже мешает корректно работать клику. Подскажите как мне пропустить вызов win.doc.addEventListener внутри функции stopNativeEvents файла dojo/touch.js из кастомного компонента.

```
function stopNativeEvents(type){
                    win.doc.addEventListener(type, function(e){
                        // Stop native events when we emitted our own click event.  Note that the native click may occur
                        // on a different node than the synthetic click event was generated on.  For example,
                        // click on a menu item, causing the menu to disappear, and then (~300ms later) the browser
                        // sends a click event to the node that was *underneath* the menu.  So stop all native events
                        // sent shortly after ours, similar to what is done in dualEvent.
                        // The INPUT.dijitOffScreen test is for offscreen inputs used in dijit/form/Button, on which
                        // we call click() explicitly, we don't want to stop this event.
                            if(!e._dojo_click &&
                                (new Date()).getTime() <= clickTime + 1000 &&
                                !(e.target.tagName == "INPUT" && domClass.contains(e.target, "dijitOffScreen"))){
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation && e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            if(type == "click" && (e.target.tagName != "INPUT" || e.target.type == "radio" || e.target.type == "checkbox")
                                && e.target.tagName != "TEXTAREA" && e.target.tagName != "AUDIO" && e.target.tagName != "VIDEO"){
                                 // preventDefault() breaks textual <input>s on android, keyboard doesn't popup,
                                 // but it is still needed for checkboxes and radio buttons, otherwise in some cases
                                 // the checked state becomes inconsistent with the widget's state
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }, true);
                }

                stopNativeEvents("click");

                // We also stop mousedown/up since these would be sent well after with our "fast" click (300ms),
                // which can confuse some dijit widgets.
                stopNativeEvents("mousedown");
                stopNativeEvents("mouseup");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось проще некуда. После очередного обновления Chrome все наладилось. Извините за беспокойство. Ответ - обновите chrome до последней версии.